# How to change control alignment depending on available space?

Tags: c#, wpf

Imagine this. I've got a `Border` which contains some custom wpf control, lets call it `MyControl`. This `Border` stretches itself when window is resized (to fill available space). `MyControl` size is fixed. Now, I want my control to have `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` when it fits the available space, and `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` when it doesn't. I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement such behaviour though.

I guess, i can subscribe to Border's `SizeChanged` event and change alignment in code-behind depending on `ActualWidth`s of `Border` and `MyControl`, but isn't there an easier way? Can this be achieved by databinding or by attached behaviour?

Comment: @NikitaBrzhak What do you mean "fits available space"? Is it when Border width value is larger then the MyControl width value?

Comment: @voo, yes. *5 more chars*

Comment: @tanuj_loop, those alignments behave differently when there isnt enough space to display control. `Left` crops control from right side, `Center` - from both sides. That is the key difference in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will automatically behave like that if you set the control's `Width` and `Height` to fixed values and `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch` instead of `Center`:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="5">
    <my:MyControl Width="200" Height="150"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Border>
```